# How to set/get select element from NSDatePicker

Tags: cocoa, nsdatepicker

I'm trying to find out a way to set/get selected element from `NSDatePicker`.

For example, if there is a `NSDatePicker` like following the selected element is year.

[image: NSDatePicker]

I'd like to get which is the selected element and want to change selected element by coding. I can change the selection only by mouse click or arrow of keyboard.

Does anyone knows about on this?

BTW, The macOS Calendar app and Fantastical2 app does this which means there must be a way to do it without using Private API.

Comment: Maybe the Calendar app or Fantastical2 app are using private API or a custom control.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the info. I gave up. :(

Comment: @Tommy https://stackoverflow.com/a/61734758/2303865